# Call by reference

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a linked list dequeed. I have created my add a word which adds a word. Because I change the head and the tail of list I was trying to use call by reference so I could change both the head and the tail of the list. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because it isn't changing the address outside of the function. 
`head` and `tail` are `NULL` when they are sent. `head` and `tail` get addresses while in the functions and then after leaving the function `head` and `tail` become `NULL` again. 
I dont understand why this is happening? Thanks for any help. 
I added the entire program! it does appear to be working fine! but it doesn't change tail and node outside of the function. 
I origially had the program wiht global varibles and then i changed that because the teacher didn't like them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <strings.h>
#include <cctype>

struct node
{
char word [10];
node *next;
node *prev;
};


using namespace std;


int display ();
void switcheroo (int, struct node*, struct node*);
void  add_Word (char [], struct node**, struct node**);
void delete_Word (char [], struct node **, struct node **);
void display_Queue (struct node*);
void display_Stack (struct node*);
void search_List (char[], struct node*);
struct node* makeNode (void);

int main ( )
{

system ("clear");
int pick;
struct node *head;
struct node *tail;
head = NULL;

cout << endl << head << " first call"<< endl;

while (pick != 6)
{
cout << endl << head << " 888888"  << endl;
pick = display ();
switcheroo (pick, head, tail);
}

return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************/

int display ()
{

int user_choice;

 cout <<"What would you like to do?\n\n";  
 cout <<"Press 1   Add a word\n";
 cout <<"Press 2   Delete a word\n";
 cout <<"Press 3   Display the data in Queue order\n";
 cout <<"Press 4   Display the data in stack order\n"; 
 cout <<"Press 5   Search the list for a word\n";
 cout <<"Press 6   Quit\n";
 cin >> user_choice;

  return user_choice;
 }
/********************************************************************/
void switcheroo (int pick, struct node* head, struct node*tail)
{
 char word [10];
 switch (pick)
    {
case 1:
    cout << "Please enter a word:\n";
    cin  >> word;
    add_Word(word, &head, &tail);
    break;
case 2:
    display_Queue(head);
    cout << "\n\nEnter a word to delete\n";
    cin >> word;
    delete_Word(word, &head, &tail);
    break;
case 3:
    display_Queue(head);
    break;
case 4:
    display_Stack(tail);
    break;
case 5: 
    display_Queue(head);
    cout << "\n\nWhat word would you like to search for?\n";
    cin >> word;
    search_List(word, tail);
    break;
case 6:
    return;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************/
void  add_Word ( char word[], struct node **head, struct node **tail)
{
struct node *var, *temp;
var = makeNode();
strcpy (var->word, word);

cout << endl << *head << endl;
cout << endl << *tail << endl;

if (*head == NULL)
{
*head = var;
cout << *head << endl;
(*head)->prev = NULL;
(*head)->next = NULL;
tail = head;


cout << endl << "00000" << *head << endl;
}
else 
{
cout << "--------------" << endl;
 temp = var;
temp->prev = NULL;
temp->next = *head;
(*head)->prev = temp;
*head = temp;
}

}
/*******************************************************************/


struct node* makeNode (void)
{
struct node* newptr;

newptr = new struct node;
if (newptr)
newptr->next = NULL;

return newptr;
}

/*******************************************************************/

void display_Queue(struct node * x)
{
int n = 01;
while (x != NULL)
{
cout << "---" << x->word << "---" << n << endl;
n++;
x = x->prev;
}

return;
} 
/*******************************************************************/
void display_Stack (struct node *x)
{
int n=1;
while (x != NULL)
{
cout << "---" << x->word << "---" << n << endl;
n++;
x = x->next;
}

return;
}
/*******************************************************************/
void delete_Word(char word [], struct node **head, struct node **tail) 
{

struct node *palabra, *x;
int n = 0; 
x = *head; 
char copy [10];
while (x != NULL)
{
strcpy (copy,x->word); 
 cout << "!!!!!!!!!!" << x->word << endl;  
if (strcasecmp (x->word, word)==0)
{
    cout << "**********"<< endl;
palabra = x;
n++;
}
x = x->next;
}

if (n==0)
cout << "NO word to delete!!! try again";


 if (n==1)
{  
if ((palabra->next == NULL) && (palabra->prev == NULL))
{ 
delete (palabra);
*head = NULL;
*tail = NULL;
}
else if (palabra->next == NULL)
{
*tail = palabra->prev;
(*tail)->next = NULL;
delete (palabra);
}
else if(palabra->prev == NULL)      
{
*head = palabra->next;
(*head)->prev = NULL;
delete (palabra);
}
else if((palabra->next != NULL)&&(palabra->prev!= NULL))
{
palabra->next->prev = palabra->prev;
palabra->prev->next = palabra->next;
delete (palabra);
}
}
}
/*******************************************************************/ 
void search_List (char word[], struct node *x)
{
int n =1;
cout << endl << word << endl;


while (x != NULL)
{
  if (strcasecmp (x->word, word)==0)
    {
    cout << "Your word has been found\n";
    cout << word << " is number:  " << n << " in the list\n\n";
    }
n++;
x = x->prev;
}
}
```

Comment: May I ask you why are you using `char[]` and your own node implementation instead of `std::list`/`std::forward_list` and `std::string`?

Comment: Not allowed to use strings on this assignment.

Comment: Please, fix indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown works fine for me as you have shown it.  `head` and `tail` are not NULL anymore after `add_Word()` exits, as expected.

With that said, your logic is a bit backwards.  You are adding words in reverse order - newer words appear in the list before older words, instead of appearing after them.  Is that what you really want?  If not, then your logic should be more like this instead:

```
struct node* makeNode()
{
    struct node *n = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    memset(n, 0, sizeof(struct node));
    return n;
}

void add_Word(char word[], struct node** head, struct node** tail)
{
    struct node* var = makeNode();
    strcpy(var->word, word);

    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = var;

    if (*tail != NULL)
    {
        var->prev = *tail;
        (*tail)->next = var;
    }

    *tail = var;
}
```

**Update**: Actually, your original `add_Word()` did have one bug I missed. It was not updating `tail` correctly.  You needed to dereference the `tail` parameter in order to update the outside variable to point at a new `node`.  You were instead updating the local `tail` parameter of `add_Word()` to point at the same address that the local `head` parameter was pointing at.  Not the same thing.

Also, in your latest code update, your `switcheroo()` function is not modifying the `head` and `tail` variables that are declared in `main()`.  You are passing those variables by value and not by pointer, like you do with `add_Word()` and `delete_Word()`.  As such, when `switcheroo()` calls `add_Word()` or `delete_Word()`, the changes they make are to the local parameters of `switcheroo()` only and are not propagated up to `main()`.

There are other problems with your code.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <strings.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>

struct node
{
    char word [10];
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};

using namespace std;


int display ();
void switcheroo (int, struct node**, struct node**);
void  add_Word (char [], struct node**, struct node**);
void delete_Word (char [], struct node **, struct node **);
void display_Queue (struct node*);
void display_Stack (struct node*);
void search_List (char[], struct node*);
struct node* makeNode (void);
void destroyNode (struct node*, struct node**, struct node**);

int main()
{
    system ("clear");

    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *tail = NULL;
    struct node *temp;
    int pick;

    do
    {
        pick = display ();
        switcheroo (pick, &head, &tail);
    }
    while (pick != 6);

    while (head != NULL)
        destroyNode (head, &head, &tail);

    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************/

int display ()
{
    int user_choice;

    do
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Press 1   Add a word" << endl;
        cout << "Press 2   Delete a word" << endl;
        cout << "Press 3   Display the data in Queue order" << endl;
        cout << "Press 4   Display the data in Stack order" << endl;
        cout << "Press 5   Search the list for a word" << endl;
        cout << "Press 6   Quit" << endl;

        if (cin >> user_choice)
        {
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            if ((user_choice >= 1) && (user_choice <= 6))
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        cout << "That is not a valid choice. Try again." << endl << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    return user_choice;
}
/********************************************************************/
void switcheroo (int pick, struct node** head, struct node** tail)
{
    char word [10];
    switch (pick)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "Please enter a word:" << endl;
            cin.getline(word, 10);
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            add_Word(word, head, tail);
            break;
        case 2:
            display_Queue(*tail);
            cout << endl << endl << "Enter a word to delete" << endl;
            cin.getline(word, 10);
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            delete_Word(word, head, tail);
            break;
        case 3:
            display_Queue(*tail);
            break;
        case 4:
            display_Stack(*head);
            break;
        case 5:
            display_Queue(*tail);
            cout << endl << endl << "What word would you like to search for?" << endl;
            cin.getline(word, 10);
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            search_List(word, *tail);
            break;
        case 6:
            return;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************/
void  add_Word ( char word[], struct node **head, struct node **tail)
{
    struct node *var = makeNode();
    strncpy (var->word, word, 10);

    var->next = *head;
    if (var->next != NULL)
        var->next->prev = var;
    *head = var;

    if (*tail == NULL)
        *tail = var;
}
/*******************************************************************/

struct node* makeNode (void)
{
    struct node* newptr = new struct node;
    memset(newptr, 0, sizeof(struct node));
    return newptr;
}

/*******************************************************************/

void destroyNode (struct node *x, struct node** head, struct node** tail)
{
    if (x == NULL)
        return;

    if (x->next != NULL)
        x->next->prev = x->prev;

    if (x->prev != NULL)
        x->prev->next = x->next;

    if (x == *head)
        *head = x->next;

    if (x == *tail)
        *tail = x->prev;

    delete x;
}

/*******************************************************************/

void display_Queue(struct node * x)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        cout << "---" << x->word << "---" << n << endl;
        x = x->prev;
    }

    return;
}
/*******************************************************************/
void display_Stack (struct node *x)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        cout << "---" << x->word << "---" << n << endl;
        x = x->next;
    }

    return;
}
/*******************************************************************/
void delete_Word(char word [], struct node **head, struct node **tail)
{
    struct node *x = *head;
    struct node *temp;
    int n = 0;

    while (x != NULL)
    {
        cout << "!!!!!!!!!!" << x->word << endl;
        if (strncmpi (x->word, word, 10)==0)
        {
            cout << "**********" << endl;

            temp = x->next;
            destroyNode (x, head, tail);
            x = temp;

            n++;
        }
        else
            x = x->next;
    }

    if (n==0)
        cout << "NO word deleted!!! try again" << endl;
}
/*******************************************************************/
void search_List (char word[], struct node *x)
{
    int n = 0;
    int found = 0;

    cout << "Searching for: " << word << endl;

    while (x != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        if (strcmpi (x->word, word)==0)
        {
            cout << "Your word has been found" << endl;
            cout << word << " is number " << n << " in the list" << endl;
            ++found;
        }
        x = x->prev;
    }

    if (found==0)
        cout << "NO word found!!! try again" << endl;
}
```

Comment: HEAD and TAIL are changed in the function! but once they leave the function HEAD and TAIL go back to NULL and then the entire program is messed up.

Comment: There is NO POSSIBLE WAY the `add_Word()` code shown earlier can make them go back to NULL when the function exits. The ONLY way would be if your own code was resetting them at a later time after the function exited. Run your code through a debugger, you will see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Your `switcheroo()` function has a bug in it that prevents the changes to the `head` and `tail` variables declared in `main()`.

Comment: I beleive you that it is a bug in switcheroo but i dont understand where could be? It is just a switch statement. Do you have any idea what the bug is? Switcheroo is just a switch statement so it finds the proper case and then it goes to the function that is called, then it returns to switcheroo after the function that is being called and then it his the break statement of that particular case and then it returns to main. I dont understand where it could

Comment: Look at the code I posted, and compare it to your original code. The bug is that `switcheroo()` takes the `head` and `tail` pointers as `struct node*` but it needs to take them as `struct node**` instead, and then you need to pass `&head` and `&tail` to `switcheroo()`, just like you do with your other functions that manipulate `head` and `tail`.  `switcheroo()` is not manipulating the variables in `main()`, that is why they stay NULL. `switcheroo()` is manipulating its local parameters instead, which is why they are not NULL while `switcheroo()` is still running.

Comment: In other words, you are passing the `head` and `tail` variables of `main()` to `switcheroo()` by value instead of by pointer, so `switcheroo()` is only manipulating its local parameters, not the original variables.